# How to fix 'list index out of range' error in python

Tags: python, excel, csv, sorting, index-error

I'm using excel to store a username and score. For example:

```
Ben,1 

Kim,9

Jeff,3

Bob,5
```

I would like to sort them using the score highest to lowest but I keep getting this error:

> list index out of range

My code:

```
import csv

import operator

sample = open("data.csv","r")

reader = csv.reader(sample,delimiter=',')

sort = sorted(reader,key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Posting the error without code-line reference is not really useful.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because of the empty line

```
import csv
import operator

result = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile,delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        if line:                #Check if line is empty
            result.append(line)

print(sorted(result,key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

---

or use `filter`

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile,delimiter=',')
    print( sorted(filter(None, reader),key=operator.itemgetter(1)) )
```